# How I can get a sequence for the differential sheaf on the blow up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at a single point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X:=\mathbb{P}^2$ and let $\pi : Y(:=\mathbb{Bl}_p) \rightarrow X$ be the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at a point $p$. Then we can get a exact sequence for the differential sheaf $\Omega_Y^1$ of $Y$ as:
$$0 \rightarrow {\cal{O}}_Y(-2f) \rightarrow \Omega_Y^1 \rightarrow {\cal{O}}_Y(-2h-f) \rightarrow 0$$
In the above sequence $f$ is a fibre of ruling (as seen $Y$ is  a ruled surface), while $h$ is the negative intersection section. My question is that how I can get this sequence in detail. Maybe it is an easy question, but I cannot get any idea for the first step. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be something roughly like this:

Write $Y$ as the total space of the projective bundle $\pi : \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}(1)) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$, . There is a bundle morphism $TY \rightarrow \pi^{*}(T\mathbb{P}^1)$ which is given by the map on tangent vectors induced by $\pi$. Note that $\pi^{*}(T\mathbb{P}^1) = \mathcal{O}_{Y}(2f)$ because the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ has degree 2. Now dualising gives the desired sequence (note that dualising reverses the direction so we have the required terms in the two positions, this was enough to convince me :)).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I followed but still have a question mark. So we have an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow K \rightarrow TY \rightarrow {\cal{O}}_Y(2f) \rightarrow 0$ and then taking dual, how I can say about the dual of $K$ is isomorphic to ${\cal{O}}_Y(-2h-f)$? I think it may comes from the relative cotangent sheaf $\Omega_{X/Y}$, but have no more idea yet.

Comment: It may be a little bit cheating, but you can get it using the fact that $Y$ is toric so $c_1$ of the tangent bundle is the sum of boundary divisors (i.e. $2f + S_{1} + S_{2}$ where $S_{i}$ are the $2$ sections. It depends what your goal is, if you want to verify that such an exact seqeunce exists then it is fine, if your goal was to compute the Chern classes of the tangent (or equivelantly cotangent) then I think you need a different method.

Comment: There is a general short exact sequence for projective bundles of $E$ over $Y$ with 4 terms  namely $0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \pi^{*}(E) \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}(1) \rightarrow T\mathbb{P}(E) \rightarrow \pi^{*}(TY) \rightarrow 0$, which can be found in textbooks. I think that the point is because $E$ splits you can pull out a $3$ term sequence and verify what the terms are. $ \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}(1)$ is the tautological bundle (subbundle of $\pi^{*}(E)$), it is relatively easy to compute the chern class of taut. bund. by restricting it to fibres, sections etc.